# Looping excel rows through excel formulas in Python

Tags: python, excel

I would love someone to help solve this problem.

1. Excel Sheet 1: Different formulas calculating different things in Columns A to E. Result in Column F (all for one scenario named "index 1")
2. Excel Sheet 2: Contains 100 scenarios (index 1 to index 100).

Problem:

a) I need to run each of the index in Sheet 2 through the formulas in Sheet 1
b) Every time i run each index through Sheet 1, I want to copy the result in column F (sheet 1) and paste it in a separate sheet (Excel sheet 3) together with the Index ID

How can this be achieved using Python? Please
I have Excel sheet 1 and Excel sheet 2, but automating the index 1 through 100 is giving me a headache. Can someone help with a python code please.

Comment: why python and not excel vba ?

Comment: Excel VBA can sometimes be slow

Comment: you would need `openpyxl` or `xlwings`. The excel sheet might need to be closed when you are executing the code becuase of read / write access. Alternatively, you would work with csv files and dataframes (in python)...  which is why excel VBA might be a more optimal solution.